# Find IMEI no in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to use IMEI no in my application. so I search for how to get IMEI no. in wp7 but every time I got DeviceUniqueId so IMEI no and DeviceUniqueId is same thing or not then how can I get IMEI number in wp7?

Answer (score 6):

For privacy and security reasons, the IMEI number is not accessible to third party developers. The `DeviceUniqueID` is not the same as the IMEI number.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this http://www.nickharris.net/2010/09/how-to-place-a-phone-call-on-windows-phone-7-using-phonecalltask/ to make a phone call on *#06#  - being the code to obtain the IMEI?