# Serial number of phone (device)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone

Is it possible to get unique number of phone (not SIM, phone number, but device number!) ??
Something like device serial number, producent code, IMEI etc?
I work with Windows Phone 7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object uniqueId;
var hexString = string.Empty;
if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId))
    hexString = BitConverter.ToString((byte[])uniqueId).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

Dont forget to specify ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE capability in the app manifest.

Comment: Is it applicable for a Device which is running Windows 10 ?

Answer (score -3):

Type `*#06#` from the desktop(home) screen to get the IMEI no

Comment: @Jacek Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426757/getting-imei-number-in-windows-phone-7