# Get IMSI and IMEI in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, imei

I know that it is not possible to get the IMSI and IMEI on Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 8, however, given the major updated with the Windows Phone 8.1, am I now able to retrieve my device IMSI and IMEI number?

Comment: Did you try with the existing one which supported for WP8?

Comment: From what I gathered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393442/how-can-i-get-imsi-and-imei-in-windows-phone-8) you can't get it, otherwise that would be the first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

**[This page](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54272/how-to-get-the-imei-number)** seems to have up-to-date, cross-platform advice for getting device ids.