# How do I find imei number in windows 8.1 phone programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, imei

I am trying to find imei number in windows phone 8.1 application programmatically and i have referred many links but cannot find anything clear.I am unable to find tapi.dll for windows 8.1 phone application so is there any alternative for tapi library.
Following are few links which i have refferred:
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/779684/How-to-use-tapi-lib-in-Csharp-windows-application

[Get IMSI and IMEI in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813388/get-imsi-and-imei-in-windows-phone-8-1)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c80fad35-df82-4c39-b263-93ea3758cadf/getting-imei-number-in-windows-phone?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Do you actually need these, or are you just looking for an [anonymous identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to use?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to retrieve the IMEI using

```
MobileBroadbandDeviceInformation.MobileEquipmentId
```

For GSM devices, the MobileEquipmentId value will be the International Mobile Equipment Identitiy (IMEI), which can be up to 15 digits long. For CDMA devices, the MobileEquipmentId value must be the electronic serical number (ESNs0, which is 11 digits long, or the mobile equipment identifier (MEID), which is 17 digits long.

**Note**
This functionality is only available to mobile operator apps and Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network operators.

Comment: I want a solution which work for both the windows phone 8.1 as well as store, which I am unable to find..do u have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try **[this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54272/how-to-get-the-imei-number)**. It seems serious and cross platform.