# Is there any way to fetch the IMEI Number of the Windows Phone device Using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.uwp

Is there any way to fetch the `IMEI Number` of the Windows Phone device Using `C#`

- windows-phone-8.1
- uwp
- xamarin.uwp
- c#
- visual-studio-2015

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847320/how-do-i-find-imei-number-in-windows-8-1-phone-programmatically help?

Comment: try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/get-imei-in-device-application-in-c-sharp-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

**[This](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54272/how-to-get-the-imei-number)** looks like what you're looking for...

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UniqueIdWinPhone))]
namespace UniqueId.WinPhone
{
    public class UniqueIdWinPhone : IDevice
    {
        public string GetIdentifier()
        {
            byte[] myDeviceId = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
            return Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceId);
        }
    }
}
```

This requires the permission `ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE`.

Comment: Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties is for Windows Phone 8
But We need for Windows phone 8.1 or UWP

Comment: Nightmare. Nightmare.