# Reading device serial number and/or IMEI from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on an app that will obtain an X.509 certificate for a device that will be used to encrypt various configuration data. Ideally, this certificate would contain information that can be correlated with procurement records. Is there any way to read the device serial number or IMEI from a universal windows app?

Answer (score 6):

As for UWP in general, to get a system unique id (not IMEI), you might want to check out these classes:

```
Windows.System.Profile.SystemIdentification
```

and

```
Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification
```

E.g.: you can query a unique device id with:

```
var buffer = SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher();
```

Which has the following remarks according to msdn:

> The ID has the following characteristics:
>
> - Unique for every system
> - Can be created offline
> - Persists across rebooting, OS upgrades/reinstalls, and so on
> - Persists across hardware modifications
> - Available in OneCore
> - Available on the factory floor for licensing purposes

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.getsystemidforpublisher.aspx

Be aware that the return type is an `IBuffer` and produces some raw (non-string-like-readable) bytes so you might need to serialize that.

More info

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.systemidentification.aspx

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.aspx

Comment: What can we use for builds previous to Anniversary Update?  Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification is not available

Comment: Do you have access to a pre-anniversary system? I thought this namespace was older then the A-update, as can be seen in this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0a587a9-7274-44c1-b7a9-60d8df639ccc/uwphtmlhow-to-get-device-uri-in-universal-windows-10-apps-with-winjs-template?forum=wpdevelop but the doc's are confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get **IMEI** of another phone with phone number information, however you can get the **device unique Id**.

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Info;

object uniqueId;
var hexString = string.Empty;
if (DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueId))
     hexString = BitConverter.ToString((byte[])uniqueId).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show("myDeviceID:" + hexString);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16395098/5576310)

Comment: I am familiar with device unique ID, but this lacks the grounding in procurement records.

Comment: I know, but unfortunately you can´t get the IMEI, it´s the same with iOS it´s not available anymore @Carl

Comment: It is possible (albeit somewhat complicated, perhaps) to read serial number and IMEI on iOS. All MDMs do it. Android and Blackberry just require a permission to read these values.

Comment: Officially it´s strictly forbidden by Apple, but there are some workarounds.

Comment: @Carl if you found this post useful, consider accepting the answer so that others can use it in the future.