# Get Windows Phone IMEI through Wifi

Tags: c#

Is it possible to get a Windows Phone's (that is connected to the same network as computer via Wi-Fi) IMEI in C# ? 
I have an inventory system built in C# for all sort of materials. I have managed to get information from remote PC with WMI, and I was wondering if it was possible with a Windows Phone

Comment: Hi, 
Typically I've accessed IMEI by running AT query commands against the 3G/4G chipset.  I'd be surprised if Windows Phone doesn't do this however I'd be even more surprised if it allows a network connected computer to interrogate this info remotely (it's identifiable data so should be kept protected)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.  See [How can I get IMSI and IMEI in Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393442/how-can-i-get-imsi-and-imei-in-windows-phone-8)  and [How can I get IMSI and IMEI in Windows Phone 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393442/how-can-i-get-imsi-and-imei-in-windows-phone-8) for discussions about how IMEI is not available programatically for Windows Phone.